# Animate when scroll - Only CSS or Wordpress plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I got a project and I am stuck; I want to make an animation when user scrolls down (animation on text/logo).

I failed to find any useful methods from google. Can anyone provide a **Fiddle** or **codepen** with scrolling animations

**P.S:** ( Only HTML/CSS, No jquery/javascript but I still can use a wordpress plugin [the website was made with wordpress]).

**[This](http://therealmaccoy.com/services-capabilities)** is the website : / As you can see, there is already an animation I made ( 3 seconds ) but when the page loads. I need it to load when you scroll down there.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this is going to be possible without Javascript. HTML / CSS alone don't have the ability to detect scrolling and apply animations. Is there a particular reason you cannot use Javascript / jQuery that we can help with? jQuery is included in WordPress itself, so it shouldn't be much of an issue?

Comment: Can you tell me how to add jquery in wordpress(can't acces the ftp) in order to select a div? Thanks

Comment: Ah... Well, you should probably get FTP access before you go too deep into this. But, if you absolutely can't, you could possibly install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-code-editor/ -- This allows you to edit JS files of a theme. So you could hypothetically install this, edit your themes main.js or script.js or whatever the main JS file is for your theme, and add in your jQuery code in there somewhere. It's really tough to get more specific without seeing your theme, but it could work. But yeah, I'd probably try to get FTP access, it'll make your life easier!